# Polymorphism and casting in Java

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

What is the difference between the way these two objects are instantiated.

`Employee emp = new Employee;`

`Employee emp = new Manager();`

What are the different methods that can be accessed for each. What is downcasting and upcasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this means is that the Manager class extends or implements the Employee class.

The second part of your question is a little unclear to me. But an example of having to cast emp is if the Manager class has a specific method which the Employee class does not. You'd need to cast emp in order to use Manager-specific methods.

Something like
`((Manager) emp).managerSpecificMethod();`

Answer (score 0):

### Polymorphism

is when a class extends or implements another class. In your example it seems like the Manager class extends Employee, therefore you can instantiate a Manager from its super class Employee. When you instantiate a Manager object this way, you will only have access to the Employee methods, but since the object created is a Manager any overridden methods in the Manager class will be used instead of those in the Employee class. This is useful if there is a method that only takes a the super class as an argument, you can instantiate it this way and pass it the sub class.

### Casting

Downcasting in your example would be:

```
Employee emp = new Manager();
Manager castedEmp = (Manager)emp;
```

Here you are instantiating a an Employee object but since you know emp is a Manager you can downcast it to Manager.

Upcasting is the opposite. You have a Manager object and you cast it to Employee like so:

```
  Employee emp = new Manager();
  Employee castedEmp = (Employee)emp;
```